# Android/Java change áéőűú to aeouu

Tags: android, regex

How can I change text such as `"áéőűú"` to `"aeouu"` in Android?

`java.text.Normalizer` is not available on Android systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.replaceAll(String, String) ?

Comment: best solution? any? it is very..none cute:(